# is there any way to handle all the events of the chrome.tabs & chrome.tabGroups & chrome.windows in one event?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i'm building a extension of chrome,
and it needs to handle the events for chrome.tabs and chrome.tabGroups and chrome.windows.

but
if i use these api independently, chrome would fire multi events for one action,
for example :

when i create a new tab in one window,
chrome will fire :

```
"chrome.windows.onFocusChanged"
"chrome.tabs.onCreated"
"chrome.tabs.onActivated"
"chrome.tabs.onUpdated"
```

is there any way to get just one fire for one action?

(any Chrome API or any way to Intergrate?)

thank @wOxxOm 's answer, solved now :

"use debounce on a separate function that's called from both events."

Comment: You can use *debounce* in each event to call your function.

Comment: debounce could solve one event repeat, but : when create a tab on chrome, there's two event (chrome.tabs.create & chrome.tabs.updated) fired, so function still runs two times in a very short time :(

Comment: You would use debounce on a separate function that's called from both events.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you very much, solved now :)